# How to change label text in C# form

Tags: c#, label, textchanged

I've an application that changes the text of the label to a serial number that is scanned using a barcode scanner. The code works up until I have buttons on my form.

I've tried (1) focusing on the label, (2) creating a groupbox and putting the label in the groupbox and focusing on that, using both tab order and this:

```
 this.ActiveControl = groupBox2;
```

And neither work.

Here is code outlining the the application:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ActiveControl = groupBox2;

        this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
        this.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyUp);
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // if keyboard input is allowed to read
        if (UseKeyboard && e.KeyData != Keys.Enter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.KeyData.ToString());
        }

        /* check if keydown and keyup is not different
         * and keydown event is not fired again before the keyup event fired for the same key
         * and keydown is not null
         * Barcode never fired keydown event more than 1 time before the same key fired keyup event
         * Barcode generally finishes all events (like keydown > keypress > keyup) of single key at a time, if two different keys are pressed then it is with keyboard
         */
        if (cforKeyDown != (char)e.KeyCode || cforKeyDown == '\0')
        {
            cforKeyDown = '\0';
            _barcode.Clear();
            return;
        }

        // getting the time difference between 2 keys
        int elapsed = (DateTime.Now.Millisecond - _lastKeystroke);

        /*
         * Barcode scanner usually takes less than 17 milliseconds to read, increase this if neccessary of your barcode scanner is slower
         * also assuming human can not type faster than 17 milliseconds
         */
        if (elapsed > 17)
            _barcode.Clear();

        // Do not push in array if Enter/Return is pressed, since it is not any Character that need to be read
        if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Return)
        {
            _barcode.Add((char)e.KeyData);
        }

        // Barcode scanner hits Enter/Return after reading barcode
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return && _barcode.Count > 0)
        {
            string BarCodeData = new String(_barcode.ToArray());
            if (!UseKeyboard)
                //MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}", BarCodeData));
                label1.Text = String.Format("{0}", BarCodeData);
            _barcode.Clear();
        }

        // update the last key press strock time
        _lastKeystroke = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
    }
```

Again, it works as soon as I take the buttons out.
Here's a pic of my the UI:

[image]

Again, the label changes, until I start adding buttons to the WinForm.
Looking at the UI, the line that says, "Please Scan Serial..." should change when the user scans the barcode.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint, does it still hit the `label1.Text = String.Format("{0}", BarCodeData);` line and just not change the text, or is that line no longer hit at all?

Comment: try changing KeyPreview to true on your form.

Comment: Thank you Trey! It works per your suggestion.